# 1990 Mercury Cougar LS stereo wire color diagram

Tags: mercury

I'm having trouble finding color coding for my Mercury Cougar. I found a diagram but it shows the stereo constant power wire is green and yellow, but there is no green and yellow in my Cougar stereo harness. It also has the cruise control wires tied in to the stereo harness, as well as the cruise constant power and switched power are backwards. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Found this for the base stereo system.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When wiring a stereo, there are typically 3 pieces.
1 - the vehicle's wiring harness with a connecter.
2 - a 'pigtail' that connects to your vehicle's harness and has open wires with standard colors.  You can find these at most auto parts stores or online.
3 - the radio's wiring harness.

When wiring up a new radio, you connect the radio's harness to the pigtail (by soldering or using crimp connectors), then plug it in to your vehicle's wiring harness.  This way, your vehicles wiring will not be modified.